# How does ring theory connects with analysis?

Tags: soft-question

I'm student who is interested in analysis but now i'm taking some graduate algebra courses.

I have to say that i enjoy a lot algebra especially ring theory.

I would like a lot to find and study aspects in analysis combined with ring theory and advanced algebra.

I know a field in analysis that uses ring and module theory.It's the theory of Banach algrbras.

Are there any more fields in analysis that use ring theory (and generally advanced algebra)?

Comment: I don't know much, but I think you may find this interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02672

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C*-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) are important in  functional analysis.

Answer (score 4):

In mathematical control theory you encounter the ring $\mathbb K^{n\times n}[x]$ of matrix polynomials. Here you can ask questions like is a given matrix polynomial A(x) invertible? Answer: it is if $\det(A(x))\in\mathbb K\setminus\{0\}$; in this case $A(x)$ is called $unimodular$.

Another question that naturally arises is what the simplest representative of $A$ under a the similarity transform $A\to SAT$ with $S$ and $T$ unimodular. This leads to the [Smith-Normal-Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Answer (score 3):

In complex analysis, one is quite often in touch with ring theory. Consider for example the set of all holomorphic(=analytic) functions on a domain (=non-empty, open, connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$) $G$, i.e.
$$ H(G) := \{ f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \, | \, f \text{ holomorphic in } G \} $$

This set, equipped with pointwise addition and multiplication, forms a commutative ring with identity element. In fact, $H(G)$ is even an integral domain. When considering the larger set $M(G)$ of meromorphic functions on $G$, this set is even a field. By using the so-called *Weierstrass factorization theorem* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), one can show that in fact $M(G)$ is the quotient field of $H(G)$. See for example Conway, "*Functions of One Complex Variable I + II*" and the books on complex analysis by Remmert. A nice paper on this topic is for example Royden, "*Rings of analytic and meromorphic functions*".

Answer (score 2):

One natural connection is with infinitesimal analysis, via the construction of the hyperreals as the quotient by a suitable *maximal ideal* MAX of the ring of sequences of real numbers, or in formulas $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb N}/\text{MAX}$.